# Ruby Savon Gem change logging configuration

Tags: ruby, wsdl, savon

I've tried changing the logging on Savon when running it against a WSDL, but have been unsuccessful in changing the logging level.

I read the docs: http://rubiii.github.com/savon/#global_configuration

I did this:

```
Savon.configure do |config|
  config.log = false            # disable logging
  config.log_level = :info      # changing the log level
  config.logger = Rails.logger  # using the Rails logger
end
```

And it complains about not knowing what configure means..  any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This documentation you linked is for savon 0.8, you may be using an older version. When in doubt, go to the source code (path is platform-dependent) and check how the code/test do it:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/savon-0.7.8
$ grep -lr log_level * 
lib/savon/logger.rb
spec/savon/request_spec.rb
$ cat spec/savon/request_spec.rb
...
Savon::Request.log_level = :info
...
```

Comment: thanks! for being a newbie at ruby I still don't know easy little tricks like this..

Comment: the documentation mentioned by @Nick is not out-dated. it's the new documentation for savon 0.8. but thanks for helping out @tokland

Comment: @rubii. You are right, sorry, I didn't check correctly. BTW, great stuff in 0.8.x, thanks for your work!

Answer (score 4):

At least as of `gem 'savon', '~> 2.3.0'`, you can add the configuration keys when instantiating the client.

```
client = Savon.client(
    log_level: :debug,
    log: true,
    pretty_print_xml: true,
    wsdl: 'http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?wsdl'
)
```