# Cucumber / Savon omit or remove logging output

Tags: ruby, logging, cucumber, savon

While running a cucumber test I am getting (in addition to the test results) a lot of debug/log related output in the form:

```
D, [2013-03-06T12:21:38.911829 #49031] DEBUG -- : SOAP request:
D, [2013-03-06T12:21:38.911919 #49031] DEBUG -- : Pragma: no-cache, SOAPAction: "", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 1592
W, [2013-03-06T12:21:38.912360 #49031]  WARN -- : HTTPI executes HTTP POST using the httpclient adapter
D, [2013-03-06T12:21:39.410335 #49031] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
...
```

Is there a way to turn this output off?  I have tried following the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217783/ruby-savon-gem-change-logging-configuration), and my config_spec.rb file is:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Savon::Config do

  let(:config) {
    config = Savon::Config.new
    config._logger = Savon::Logger.new
    config.log_level = :error     # changing the log level
    HTTPI.log = false           # to total silent the logging.
    config

  }

  describe "#clone" do
    it "clones the logger" do
      logger = config.logger
      clone = config.clone

      logger.should_not equal(clone.logger)
    end
  end

  it "allows to change the logger" do
    logger = Logger.new("/dev/null")
    config.logger = logger
    config._logger.subject.should equal(logger)
  end

  it "allows to change the log level" do
    Savon::Request.log_level = :info
    config.log_level = :error
    config._logger.level.should == :error
  end

  it "allows to enable/disable logging" do
    config.log = false
    config._logger.should be_a(Savon::NullLogger)
    config.log = false
    config._logger.should be_a(Savon::Logger)
  end

end
```

But the logging still showing when I run the cucumber tests.

Comment: What version of Savon are you using? 2.1.0? I hope you had checked http://savonrb.com/version2.html#changes

Comment: savon (1.2.0). Must use this version (it is a dependency from a third party)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By looking  at the documentation for the [Savon API](http://savonrb.com/#configuration) you seem to be able to silence the logging by doing:

```rb
Savon.configure do |config|
  config.log = false
 end
```

The snippet above could be put in your [Cucumber World](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World) or in `features/support/env.rb` in order to silence the logging in Cucumber as well.

Comment: Thanks, this along with <<HTTPI.log = false>> achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Logs could be useful for debugging. So rather than silencing completely it might be better to put them in rails logs instead.

Here is how to do it in savon 2:

```
# config/initializers/savon.rb
HTTPI.logger = Rails.logger

# when initializing client
@client = Savon.client wsdl: '...', logger: Rails.logger
```